# Cygwin git and git bash path confusion

Tags: vim, cygwin, git-bash, vundle

So I wanted to install some vim plugins using Vundle, I got everything set up, ran PluginInstall command and got this:

> fatal: Unable to create temporary file: Result too large

I should mention that I have both git-bash and cygwin git package installed on my environment. [image]

I did some googling and found that I shouldn't use windows version of git through cygwin, installed cygwin git package, tried again to no avail. Turns out even though I have installed the cyg pkg, cygwin is still using the git-bash one.

[image]

I tried manually pulling the plugin with cygwin's git version and it worked. So how do I force cygwin to use it's own package. In my user path variable resides only cygwin's bin folder, git-bash is in the system's path variable. How do I force the user path one to take precedence over the git-bash version? Shouldn't that be the dafault behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Seems to do the trick, I don't know if that is the optimal solution but it works. I just plugged this into my bashrc.

```
export PATH="C:\cygwin64\bin"
```